# Without using Nested Gridview showing nested rows with contols in single Gridview

Tags: asp.net, gridview

i want to show nested rows in a `gridview` which contains web controls, these rows will be displayed when a `gridview` visible row is clicked. Please help me....

Thanks in advance

Comment: nested rows are the result of same `DataSource` as of the parent `GridView` or its coming from different query result?

Comment: Same datasource as of the parent gridview

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried repeater control?

With repeater you can define custom Header, Item and Footer template and of course you can define custom control/Nested rows inside Item template.

Check here on [How to use Repeater control](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/5089e0/how-to-use-repeater-control-in-Asp-Net/)

You may also try to use literal control to build runtime Html table structure[nested rows] by iterating through the resulting datasource

Sample below:

```
foreach (DataRow drTR in dtTemp.Rows)
            {

                #region "TR Building"

                sb.Append("<tr>");
                sb.Append("<td>");
                sb.Append(drTR["SKU"].ToString());
                sb.Append("</td>");
                sb.Append("<td>");
                sb.Append(drTR["SKUDESC1"].ToString());
                sb.Append("</td>");
                sb.Append("<td>");
if(dtYY.Rows.Count > 0)
{
sb.Append("<table>");
}
foreach(DataRow drX in dtYY.Rows)
{
                sb.Append("<td>");
                sb.Append(drTR["Item1"].ToString());
                sb.Append("</td>");
                sb.Append("<td>");
                sb.Append(drTR["Item2"].ToString());
                sb.Append("</td>");

                sb.Append("<td>");
                sb.Append(drTR["Item3"].ToString());
                sb.Append("</td>");


}
sb.Append("</table>");
}
                sb.Append("</td>");                   
                sb.Append("</tr>");
} 
ltData.Text = sb.ToString();
```

Comment: Can you give one example?

Comment: The literal control[ltData] needs to be placed inside body section<tbody> of HTML table